# How to increase height and width of '<rect>' automatic base on content? i want to increase <rect> height and width automatic?

Tags: php, svg

How to increase height and width of `<rect>` base on content? i want to increase  height and width automatic?

```html
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill-opacity="0" style="stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
  <foreignObject x="40" y="40" width="100" height="100">
  <div>test</div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

i want height and width should be base on content?

Comment: Do you need to use `foreignObject`? You can use the `<text>` element instead.

Comment: i need foreignObject. can you please tell me how to set width and height auto base on content in svg ```<rect>```

Comment: What do you mean in PHP? All I can see here is SVG.

Comment: yes in svg only

Comment: SVG doesn't really have automatic sizing. You could implement something in javascript.

Comment: can we do this on server side like php.